# Is it ok to make suggestions for the website here?

Tags: discussion

I looked through FAQ and it didn't say if it was ok or not to make suggestions to the general stackoverflow website so just asking here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq). (Please read the very first section.)

Comment: What sort of suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion on the point system on this site.

Comment: this question should be migrated to meta.meta.stackoverflow

Comment: @SamIam Meta is meta enough - see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta).

Answer (score 9):

I assume by suggestions you are referring to *suggesting new features*.

The [meta.stackoverflow FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq) states that you can post questions here dealing with (umongst other things), feature requests.

> If your question is about:
>
> - Stack Overflow
> - Stack Exchange
> - Stack Overflow Careers
> - Promotions & Advertising
> - Support, **feature requests**, or bug reports for the core
>     Stack Exchange engine that powers all Stack Exchange websites

So yes, you can post here on meta suggestions you may have that are relevant to Stack Overflow or even the entire Stack Exchange network.

---

When making a feature request or suggestion, please explain **why** you think this is a good idea.  Saying "I think this would be cool" or "I'd find this useful" is not enough.  You'll have to show how your suggestion would benefit the site *and it's users* as a whole.

Some tips for [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) posts -

- Mockups help people considering your suggestion to visualize your idea.  It leaves no guessing room and avoids misunderstandings.
- Use-cases will help to explain how this new feature would affect the flow of the user experience.
- Thick skin will help you shake off the possible downvotes on your request;  [Downvotes on meta are slightly different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) than on the main site.  They indicate that someone doesn't agree with your opinion or doesn't want to see your feature request implemented.  They don't necessarily mean that there is something wrong with your post.  Keep this in mind!
- Remember that people generally don't like changes.  They are comfortable with the system in it's current state and might be weary of any possible changes to their favourite Q&A site.  Be careful when criticizing existing features; You don't want people to disagree with you simply because of the tone of your post.

Comment: Not new features, just a suggestion on the current answer useful/not useful point system.

Comment: If you are suggesting some functionality that doesn't exist yet it would still be considered a feature-request.

Comment: @nhat Especially with well established features, make sure you look through relevant discussions we already had here on Meta SO. Some of them have been quite extensively debated. Perhaps your idea was already thought of. If not, feel free to ask.

Comment: Ok I search for the useful arrows for a similar question but it wasn't there so I'll post the question.. Thanks!